# Extracting typescript signatures from an object into an interface

Tags: typescript, interface, react-redux, typescript-typings

I have a habit where I seem to duplicate a lot of typings when passing information in redux. Is there any way to automatically generate the interface Props when they are all defined in ActionCreators? See the code below:

```
import { bindActionCreators, Dispatch } from "redux";
const ActionCreators = {
  foo: (a: string): string => ("foo" + a),
  bar: (a: number): string => ("bar" + a),
  baz: (a: boolean): number => (a ? 256 : 123)
};

interface Props {
  foo: (a: string) => string;
  bar: (a: number) => string;
  baz: (a: boolean) => number;
}

const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch: Dispatch): Props => {
  return bindActionCreators(ActionCreators, dispatch);
};
```

Understanding bindActionCreators is not required, the real issue here is getting all the signatures on ActionCreators the be extracted to an interface such as Props.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just use the `typeof` type operator to get the type of any constant. You can then use a type alias to give it a name

```
const ActionCreators = {
  foo: (a: string): string => ("foo" + a),
  bar: (a: number): string => ("bar" + a),
  baz: (a: boolean): number => (a ? 256 : 123)
};

type Props = typeof ActionCreators;
/*
Same as
type Props = {
  foo: (a: string) => string;
  bar: (a: number) => string;
  baz: (a: boolean) => number;
} 
*/
```

While there are subtle differences between interfaces and type aliases in this case they should be equivalent.

**Edit**

Follow-up question in the comments: How can I change the return type to void for all member function ?

To do this you need to use a mapped type to map the original type to a new type and a conditional type to extract the argument types of the original function:

```
type ArgumentTypes<T> = T extends (...a: infer A) => any ? A: [] //Conditional type extracts the argument types
type Props = {
  // Mapped type, maps the keys of the original type to a new type
  // with the same keys, and with each key being a function with the same argument as the original 
  // but returning void.
  [P in keyof typeof ActionCreators]: (...a: ArgumentTypes<typeof ActionCreators[P]>) => void
}
```

Comment: That was easy. Thanks. I actually also want to change the return value in Props to void. Is that also as trivial?

Comment: @MrMamen not trivial, nu bo that hard either, I'll add it to the answer shortly

Comment: @MrMamen I added the answer to the follow-up, don't forget to upvote ;)